# How to learn java spring on digital ocean

Tags: java, spring

So this is a complete newb question. I have learnt a bit of java and am moving on to Spring. Could I do all my development on Digital Ocean instead of setting up an IDE like eclipse on my laptop? I have created an Ubuntu droplet on Digital Ocean. I am sure i can run some sudo commands to install eclipse. How would I run a graphical IDE though? I wouldnt be able to do that through putty.

Does it make sense to try what I am saying or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: I learned Spring without ever using an IDE. It's just a class library (ok, with a Napoleon complex), all you need is the documentation and a way to edit, compile and run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused here.

DigitalOcean is a provider for virtual machines on which you can run your application on. These remote servers are usually not suitable to develop software.

Normally you want to develop you application with an IDE you have installed locally and then run the finished, tested and compiled version in your production environment on the server.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought the same thing you mentioned. But I kept getting confused by their platform for developers. Posts like the one below confused me even more:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/local-development-vs-development-droplet